# In which cases I will needed to call to destructor myself?

Tags: c++, class, destructor

According to what I read about classes and in particular about destructors, in the end of the running, the destructor called automatic. If so, in which cases I will needed to call to destructor myself (or that it's will not be).

Comment: Do you mean directly invoking the destructor? There's only one case where you need to do that, when you constructed something via placement `new`

Comment: Wanting to use placement new, that's the only case.

Comment: The only reason to ever want to explicitly call a destructor is to witness [object slicing](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/022.htm) for real.

Comment: @SombreroChicken And when I will want to allocate (by a `new`)  a variable in type of the class?

Comment: you want to use `new` if you like pain and trouble. When you need to call `new` is a different question :P

Comment: @Jor.Mal: You don't. Use objects with automatic storage duration, and C++ containers. There is no place for `new` or `delete` in C++ today.

Comment: btw dont confuse calling `delete` with calling the destructor. Those are two related, though different things

Comment: @user463035818 If I allocated a variable in type of the class (by `new`)so I need to call destructor manually and in the destructor will be the `delete`, not?

Comment: its not the complete truth, but close enough: You never need to call the destructor directly!

Comment: @Jor.Mal You should destroy the object with `delete` - this will first use the destructor and then free the memory the object occupied. There's a fair chance that you will never encounter a situation where explicit use of the destructor is a good thing.